# Unable to copy using cp -R command

Tags: unix

When I am doing cp -R at my system

```
     cp -R  \[Bark\]\ Java/ /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/
```

its throwing this message

```
      cp: /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Advanced: Read-only file system

      cp: [Bark] Java//Advanced:unable to copy extended attributes to /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Advanced: Read-only file system.
```

I guess I need to make the backup disk in write mode
How to change the mode of the backup disk.

Comment: Try re-mounting the backup disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting on many UNIX systems is controlled by the `etc/fstab` file (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)). This usually specifies mount options for each device.

You need to change the mount options for the device you're interested in.

If you examine the `/etc/fstab` file on your system, you should see something along the lines of `ro` in the options column.

If you change that to `rw` and then remount it, it should be writeable.

You may want to change it back when you're done so as to protect the information on it.

---

For Mac OSX, `fstab` is still used but the file systems may also be under the control of `automount` - look up the man pages for `automount` and `autofs.conf` for information on how to configure those.

Comment: @user1590011: I believe OSX still uses the fstab for mounting, as well as other methods - I've updated the answer.

Comment: I googled for it and found this  http://superuser.com/questions/336455/mac-lion-fstab-is-deprecated-so-what-replaces-it-to-prevent-a-partition-from-m